# Why this answer is different from other

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

Please look at [Javascript best practices - where's the best place to define a helper function inside a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896130/javascript-best-practices-wheres-the-best-place-to-define-a-helper-function-i)

Here Mr. Philipp's answer I am getting like below

[image]

May be this answer is deleted, but as I know deleted answers does not allow to edit, flag etc. but I can edit, or Flag it.

I don't know Why???

Comment: it has 4 downvotes and therefore receives the `downvoted-answer` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post is just "muted" due to its downvotes.

If it was deleted (and you had 10K rep) it would have a pink background like this:
[image]